# my script "GET URL from google document" does not work any more - server failure WHY?

Tags: google-apps-script

In general I want to print the URL of the google document I am actually working with in a text field.

If I copy the google sheet the function should also work for the new document.

I scripted a solution which was working for 20 month and now I have a problem.

Now I would like to know what could happen? Why do I have a server problem? Is is it possible to have to many google documents, (i have ~9000 - it works as a small ERP system) that the server got problems?

Formula in Google sheet:

```
=hyperlink(getSheetUrl()
```

Code in Script editor:

```
function getSheetUrl() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SS.getActiveSheet();
  var url = '';
  url += SS.getUrl();
  url += '#gid=';
  url += ss.getSheetId(); 
  return url;
}
```

This is the error message in my document:

> Error: Server error occurred. Please try saving the project again. (Row 0).

- If I try to save the project in my script editor I get no failure.
- If I try to run the project in my script editor I get:

  > A server error has occurred. Please try to save the project again.

Comment: I can't re-create this issue - your script works fine on my sheet.

Comment: FWIW, you could get the same result by copying the URL of the webpage.

Comment: Can you post the full script? Are you running the getSheetUrl function? Because i'm running your code and there's no problem.

Comment: I also managed to replicate the error and found this issue tracker https://b.corp.google.com/issues/138733069

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

Today I started the system and everything works fine.

Yesterday i was also able to run my code in a new enviroment, but i was not able to copy a existing document. there i got the failure.

Maybe it was really because the lan connection was to weak. 
My company is a very rural area ;)

I will take an eye on that,

By the way. 
Does anyone has another idea how to get the link from a document and print it in a textfield in the same document (hopefully you know what i mean)